# combine 2 mysql queries into options of a select field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, foreach

totally confused by this! I have need to dynamically generate a dropdown box from holidays in a db. Basically, because there are more than one visit to each location, I need a user visible UI - which I want to set as the holiday start date.

So a typical dropdown option would look like: Benidorm 01/01/15

So, I can get the holiday name and id from Table X in the db. However, the start date is in a separate db table (table Y) and is Identifiable from the product_id and field_id.

I'm really confused by how I can a) extract the 2 pieces of info, and then combine into an option while I run through a fOREACH to create the field options.

**OH, and to confuse matters, I need to pre-select an option IF a Get variable is set (Which will be the holiday name and start date.**

Hope this makes sense? I've spent about 3 hours on this so far. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep in mind that SQL's purpose is to use clauses like `SELECT` and `JOIN` to derive result sets (virtual tables) from combinations of existing tables. Creating the list you you have described sounds possible using SQL, but there's no way to help you further with the details you've given.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, for future reference, what further info could I have provided to make the question more 'accessible'? I want to be a good "Stack Overflow-er"! :)

Comment: You can start by reading this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  By the way, it's more fun being a bad stack overflower.

Comment: @AnthonyB, many good SO questions contain a little bit of sample code. Questions about SQL queries sometimes show some table definitions and a sample of the desired result set. People who make guesses and try to answer questions like yours with sample code sometimes misoverestimate the questioners' understanding, and end up with comment streams that say things like "that didn't work: it gave a syntax error."  It takes most of us forty hours of work to get from `<?php echo "hello world." ?>` to displaying our first menu based on database contents. With respect, you have about 37 hours to go.

Comment: But don't lose heart! It's worth learning all these layers: `<form>` /HTML / HTTP / PHP / SQL . You'll get there. Keep plugging.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. Will do. Can anyone explain this code below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### TABLE HOLIDAY

holiday_id
holiday

---

### TABLE DATE

date_id
holiday_id
date

```
$query = "SELECT holiday h
          FROM holiday
          LEFT JOIN date d
          ON h.holiday_id = d.holiday_id";


//Not sure what your connection method is but fetch your rows here for example
//We put the rows in $rows
$get = $_GET['yourgetname'];

<select name="holiday">
  <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['holiday'].$row['date']; if($get ==  $row['holiday'].$row['date']) { ?> selected <?php } ?>"><?= $row['holiday'].$row['date']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm totally confused by that answer. My connection method will be  a db call in CMS Made Simple

Comment: With connection method i meant PDO, mysqli, mysql? Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I'll by using mySQL. I dont fully understand the SQL query that's all.

Comment: Also, the bit about the GET variable - is that going to mess things up much?